# A triangle and its median in complex plane.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Let $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ be vertices of the triangle $\triangle ABC$. And given that $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|$. Then the median through $A$ cuts the circumcircle at which point? 
We need to get the answer in terms of the complex numbers $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$.

Any hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify and particularize this problem by dividing the three complex numbers by $-z_1$, giving us $-1$ (let's call it $w_1$), $w_2=-\dfrac{z_2}{z_1}$, and $w_3=-\dfrac{z_3}{z_1}$. These three points give us a similar triangle to the original, rotated around the origin and shrunk so that the three new points are on the unit circle. When we find the $n$, the intersection of the median of this triangle and the unit circle, we can multiply that by $-z_1$ to get the answer to the original problem. So let's find $n$ in terms of $w_2$ and $w_3$.

[image: Unit circle and median of inscribed triangle]

The relevant median goes through the point $-1$ and the midpoint of $w_2$ and $w_3$ which is

$$m=\frac{w_2+w_3}2=-\frac{z_2+z_3}{2z_1}$$

By high-school geometry we see that the central angle for $n$ is twice the inscribed angle for $m$ relative to the point $-1$. $n$ is the point with that double-sized angle (argument for complex numbers) and distance $1$ from the origin (modulus $1$ for complex numbers). The final answer to the problem is $-z_1\cdot n$, or

> $$-z_1\operatorname{cis}\left(2\arg\left[1-\frac{z_2+z_3}{2z_1}\right]\right)$$

or, if the function $\operatorname{cis}(\phi)=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$ is not familiar,

> $$-z_1e^{2i\arg\left(1-\frac{z_2+z_3}{2z_1}\right)}$$

These are the "simplest" forms of the answer in the sense that only one variable is repeated in the formula. We can use a more familiar complex function like conjugate or modulus if we use the facts that

$$\operatorname{cis}(\arg[u])=\frac{u}{|u|}$$

and

$$\operatorname{cis}(2\arg[u])=\frac{u}{\overline u}$$

and get these other expressions for the answer:

> $$-\overline z_1\cdot\frac{(z_2+z_3-2z_1)^2}{|z_2+z_3-2z_1|^2}$$

and

> $$-\overline z_1\cdot\frac{z_2+z_3-2z_1}{\overline z_2+\overline z_3-2\overline z_1}$$

Comment: I followed your solution all along . Just one question why divide by - z1 ; +z1 would make it a bit easier. :-)

Comment: @Sudhanshu: I did divide by $+z_1$ at first, but I got to a point where I could not continue geometrically. I then used algebra on coordinates and got an answer. When I simplified I got an equivalent of my third highlighted answer, surprisingly simple. I struggled to understand that expression then hit on a geometric way to get that answer. However, dividing by $+z_1$ left the angles in a non-standard position so the geometry was significantly harder than what I presented in this answer. I then saw that dividing by $-z_1$ made the geometry *much* easier.

Comment: @Sudhanshu: (continued) So the summary is that dividing by $+z_1$ was helpful but much less helpful than dividing by $-z_1$. If you see a "bit easier" way of using $+z_1$ and handling the central angle in a non-standard position, you are smarter than I. Now you see why I spent so much effort on a simplified version of my answer. Thanks for the enjoyable problem!

Comment: Thanks for a very good and easy to follow answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Note that, since $z_1$,$z_2$, and $z_3$ all have equal magnitude, then they all lie on a common circle centred at the origin. Observe that this circle is the circumcircle of your triangle.

Now just create a line which goes through the point A and the mid-point of the opposite side.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I could draw the figure but finding the point of intersection in terms of z1 ,z2 & z3 I wasn't able to do. How can I use the fact that it is the median any hint ??

Comment: The median line goes through the mid-point of the opposite side. The mid-point of two points is $\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}$. So can you find the line now? Remember that the line is a real, not complex, variable function; a parametrisation, rather.